# how do i create an array of a string object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

i want to create an array of variable $link to get all the links in array so that i can process them simultaneously outside curly braces

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");


$html = file_get_html($url);

$i=0;
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a'); 
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) 
{
    $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
    $link  = trim($linkObj->href);

    //if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) 
    {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    }

   $descr = $html->find('span.st',$i); // description is not a child element of H3 thereforce we use a counter and recheck.
   $i++;   
}
```

Comment: Stop downvoting if you don't know the answer.

Comment: you haven't explained what the problem is or what is happening ( or not ) - that is probably why your question was downvoted

Comment: @Azhar stop assuming that people downvote a question because they don't know the answer

Comment: do you see the variable $link ??? if i print/echo it inside the braces it gives me all the links but i want to use it as an array. how do i do that as it's a string? @RamRaider

Comment: @Azhar - why are you building it as a string in the first place?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins because i can !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array and push matches.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");


$html = file_get_html($url);

$links = array();
$i=0;
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a'); 
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) 
{
    $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
    $link  = trim($linkObj->href);


  //   if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) 
{
   array_push($links, $link);        
 } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
   continue;
   }

$descr = $html->find('span.st',$i); // description is not a child element of H3 thereforce we use a counter and recheck.
$i++;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a array variable, and add it to use it later.

Before Loop,

```
$myLinks = [];
```

And, Just after this line,

```
 $link = $matches[1];
 $myLinks[] = $link;
```

Now, you can use the array $myLinks, Hope this was what you needed.